# Search View with Room

Tags: android, android-room

I am trying to find a way to get data from `Room` when searching on Search bar. My database has 200000 rows of data.

I have found a relative article http://www.zoftino.com/android-search-functionality-using-searchview-and-room, but it is wrong. He registers an observer everytime the text changes. Is there another way?

Comment: you can query database on keyboard enter/search button like `google search`

Comment: @sneharc But what if want to search on text change?

Answer (score 2):

Why not try querying in chunks so that the `CursorWindowSize` overflow doesn't occur. You can have your DAO configured for

```
interface MyDbObjectDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE mySearchName LIKE :value LIMIT :startIndex, :endIndex")
    fun mySearchQueryBetween(value: String, startIndex: Int, endIndex: Int): Single<List<MySearchData>>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE mySearchName LIKE :value LIMIT :tillIndex")
    fun mySearchQueryStart(value: String, tillIndex: Int): Single<List<MySearchData>>
}
```

If the data that is being returned is also huge, then I recommend that you have a look into the `PagingLibrary` from android https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/ and integrate it into room. This will help you to page the results that you would essentially show on the UI.

Finally you can have a recursive call with the window of the index

```
class MyRepository(val myDao: MyDbObjectDao) {
    private val searchProcessor = BehaviorProcessor.create<List<SearchData>>()
    private var searchIndex = 1

    fun queryMySearch(value: String) : Flowable<List<SearchData>> {
        startSearch(value)
        return searchProcessor.hide()
    }

    private fun startSearch(value: String) {
        if (searchIndex * searchableWindow) >= myDao.totalRowCount()) {
            searchProcessor.onComplete()
            return
        }
        if (searchIndex = 1) {
            myDao.mySearchQueryStart(value, searchableWindow)
                 .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                 .subscribe({ onSearchCall(value, it) }, { searchProcessor.onError(it) })
        } else {
             myDao.mySearchQueryBetween(value, searchableWindow.startIndex, searchableWindow.endIndex)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe({ onSearchCall(value, it) }, { searchProcessor.onError(it) })
        }

    }

    private fun onSearchCall(value: String, list: List<MySearchData>) {
        if (list.isNotEmpty()){
            searchProcessor.onNext(list.map { it.toSearchData() })
        }
        searchIndex++
        startSearch(value)
    }

    private val Int.startIndex : Int
         get() = this * (searchIndex -1)

    private val Int.endIndex : Int
         get() = this * searchIndex

    companion object {
        private const val searchableWindow = 200
    }
}
```

in your view you can

```
class MySearchFragment : BaseFragment(), SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
    override fun onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
         viewModel.queryMySearchToRepo(newText)
              .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread)
              .subscribe(this@MySearchFragment::adaptList, { it.printStackTrace() }, {
                  recyclerView?.hideLoadingProgress() 
              })
         return true;
    }

    private fun adaptList(list: List<SearchData>) {
        // set or add data to the adapter accordingly
        // with notifyRangeInserted(adapterList.size -1, list.size)
    }
}
```

All are asynchronous operations with synchronous recursion so that the DB query is not too frequent and also you'll not encounter the CursorWindow overflow > 2mb. Hope this helps

*Note*: **This example makes use of Rx Java2, hence the subscription calls**

Answer (score 1):

It's not recommended hitting such big database on `onQueryTextChange` but still if you want to, using `TimerTask` can reduce number of hits on database

```
    Timer timer;
    long delay = 2000;  //user input delay

    private void cancelAndReschedule() {
        if (timer != null) {
            timer.cancel();
        }

        timer = new Timer();
        TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                //query database

                new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        //update ui
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        timer.schedule(task, delay);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        cancelAndReschedule();
        return true;
    }
```

Another approach would be using `AutoCompleteTextView` with pre-loaded suggestion list and on `itemclick` you can query the database